# Should we use "the" before "current"?

Tags: word-usage, articles, adjectives, definite-article

I was wondering wether it's necessary to use definite article before "current" when it is used as adjective.

For example:

> 1. According to (the) current forecast it should be raining.
> 2. Should I disconnect my phone from (the) current charger?
> 3. The Prime Minister in (the) current speech is explaining...

I'm stuck because "current" is an adjective here and due to that fact it shouldn't require any article, but on the other hand all nouns require some determiner or quantifier and maybe we should keep "the" in presented sentences?

Comment: Why do you think adjectives have any bearing on article use?

Answer (score 1):

I think in the cases you mentioned the "the" is necessary as you are actually referring to objects. Imagine replacing "current" with "interesting", "cold" or even nothing - it doesn't change the necessity of the "the".

There may be more idiomatic constructions like "in current times" which behave different.