# Using a/an/the before "current"

Tags: word-choice, articles

In the following sentence

`` ... , where `id` is supposed to contain current vendor id ``
should I use one of the `a/an/the` before `current` or it's just fine without it?

Comment: _"...or is it just fine without it?"_ I would use _the_, as it is referring to a specific thing.

Comment: Does [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178601/should-we-use-the-before-current?rq=1) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it appears that you're describing an ID which has previously been mentioned (which I'm inferring from the use of 'current').

Therefore, I would suggest using 'the', to make the sentence:

> ..., where `id` is supposed to contain **the** current vendor ID.

*(also note the capitalisation of 'ID', as an abbreviated form of 'identification' or 'identifier)*

No article would be incorrect here, as articles are generally always needed unless talking about indefinite plurals. However, no article would also be appropriate when using short form, which may be a possibility if you adjust your style slightly:

> ..., where `id` is supposed to contain current vendor ID. *(lack of article feels out of place, as the rest of the sentence is written verbosely)*

> ... -- `id` is current vendor ID *(rest of phrase also written in abbreviated form, therefore lack of article makes sense in context)*

'An current' is also incorrect since 'current' begins with a consonant sound, so 'a' should be used instead. However, 'a current' is generally rarely used and unidiomatic in many cases; the only possible use I can think of for it is when describing one of a plurality of options, i.e. in place of 'one of the' + plural - e.g. 'A current affair commonly being discussed is ...'. However, in all of the following cases 'a current' is unidiomatic:

> I would like to meet a current lawyer (consider 'contemporary' instead, or, if you already have a lawyer, use 'the')

> Place a current item onto the conveyor (consider 'the' instead, presuming there is only one item being placed at a time)

> Take a current medication (consider 'the' instead)